# C# Exchange PowerShell pipeLine Invoke is raising a CmdletInvocationException for null parameter values

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to get a simple PowerShell command output into C#, using the functionality found in the `System.Management.Automation` namespace.

I have the Exchange console on my machine, and can issue commands successfully from the console, but from C# I get an error I don't understand.

Here's the sample code that should get some simple server information:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
    PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010", out snapInException);

    using (Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig))
    {
        myRunSpace.Open();

        using (Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
        {
            Command serverCommand = new Command("Get-MailboxServer");

            pipeLine.Commands.Add(serverCommand);
            Collection<PSObject> server = pipeLine.Invoke();
            foreach (PSObject cmdlet in server)
            {
                string cmdletName = cmdlet.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(cmdletName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The actual error occurrs on the pipeLine.Invoke() line:

> **System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException was unhandled**
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: parameters
>   Source=System.Management.Automation

I have tried adding parameters, for example the server Identity, but the same thing happens:

```
using (Pipeline pipeLine = myRunSpace.CreatePipeline())
{
    Command serverCommand = new Command("Get-MailboxServer");
    serverCommand.Parameters.Add("Identity", mbServerName);
    pipeLine.Commands.Add(serverCommand);
    Collection<PSObject> server = pipeLine.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: I see that you're not checking snapInException or info. Is it possible that the rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn call is failing?

Answer (score 2):

add these line to your app.config file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the command with `Get-Process` and it works fine. It seems to be an issue with how the exchange cmdlets work ( even though `Get-Mailboxserver` also has a variant that doesn't take in any parameter.)

This thread talks about the issue and proposes an alternate solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/48da1346-f47e-4ba9-9747-428fe07b4492/